# Stellen - Putting, or putting away?

Tags: verb, expression

I was looking at [this tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/PolizeiSachsen/status/1153322997085868033) from the Police is Saxony, and I couldn't help but to be stranged...

> Einen Trickbetrüger stellten unsere Einsatzkräfte in #Dresden.

[image]

I can imagine what they were trying to say but... To me this sentence sounds as the police put a con man on the street! That is probably the exact opposite of what happened, no?

How does "stellen" mean "put away", instead of "put in". They are exact opposites, no?

Comment: this basically means that they arrested him (or are literally seconds away from doing that)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/stellen) says about *stellen*

> 4. jmdn. zum Stehenbleiben zwingen

(force someone to stop (running, walking etc.))

It can well come as a surprise to come across this meaning of *stellen*. It's used whenever a criminal is involved, and is what the police tries to or successfully does (like in your example).

Once the suspect is *gestellt*, he is no longer able to or trying to get away and then the police can go on doing their work and, maybe, arrest them.

Comment: So in this context it means kinda like "stopped"? Seems a rather ambiguous way to put it...

Comment: It's not ambiguous when used in connection to the police. Once the police did that, it has this specific meaning. Imagine a police officer pointing a gun at the suspect who raises their arms - that's the mental picture (*Stehenbleiben oder ich schieße!*).

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent In this case it's more like "stopped/spotted/caught and arrested". [Duden's example](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stellen) says: "zum Stehenbleiben zwingen und dadurch in seine Gewalt bekommen"

Comment: It can also be used in a military context, e.g. when a battleship forces an enemy ship to either fight or surrender.

Comment: This use of *stellen* is from animals hunting their prey. The *put themselves* into the way of the prey.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent: It's not very ambiguous because "stellen" in the meaning of "to put" hardly ever occurs without indicating a destination (e.g. "auf den Tisch", "vor die Wand", etc.).

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent It is completely clear for any native speaker and is the idiomatic. "Jemanden stellen" means to stop someone and make sure they can not escape. It can be used for arresting a fleeing person, it can be used for an hunter catching prey, and can be used metaphorically in sports, for example sometimes in biking ("Der Ausreißer wurde von den Verfolgern 1km vor dem Ziel gestellt."). It is just not the same meaning as "Etwas (hin- oder auf-) stellen".

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent In fact, if it means "put something somewhere", you can replace "stellen" with "hinstellen" or "aufstellen", and if it means catching someone you can not. English has a similar construction - "placing someone under arrest" means just arresting them - it doesn't necessarily mean placing them somewhere physically.

Comment: @Polygnome if you didn't add "under arrest" it would sound weird. It would sound like "the police placed a conman" which is what I understood here in the German version. I'm sure it's clear for a native. But for me, it was not. I hoped some understanding.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you say that it hardly ever occurs without indicating a destination, but in this case... It didn't indicate a destination

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent This usage of *stellen* is quite specific. It's somehow connected to violence, see the examples (a battle, hunt and stopping a criminal - the latter case is the most common one with the police stopping a suspect). Consider it technical language. Colloquially, you could say "Die Polizei hat ihn geschnappt!" or "Sie haben ihn!" etc.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent: I said "stellen" in the sense of "to put" hardly ever occurs without a destination. As you correctly remarked, no such destination is indicated in the case at hand, which implies "stellen" does *not* mean "to put" here.